# Ways to recover SQL Server account password?

Tags: sql-server-2005, c#-3.0

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have so many user accounts in my SQL Server. But I don't know the SQL Server account password. Is there any ways to get the password of the account using SQL Server or .Net (C#)?. I have the SQL Server administrative privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have administrative privileges you can reset the password.

Comment: @Jibu P C_Adoor, SQL Server doesn't store plain text passwords. Only the password hash is stored which by definition is non-reversible. So reset or brute-force. There are even [commercial tools](http://lastbit.com/sqlpassword/) that might help you brute-force it.